# Update CoreData attribute of type Int32

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to get the value of an core data attribute and after getting this object/value I'd like to update it. This is my code:

```
var numberOfChanges:Int32?
numberOfChanges = theme.valueForKey("numberThemeChanged") as Int32
var newValueThemeChanges:Int32?
newValueThemeChanges = numberOfChanges+1
theme.setValue(newValueThemeChanges, forKey: "numberThemeChanged")
```

I'm getting the following errors:

1. `Type 'Int32' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'` in this line of code: `numberOfChanges = theme.valueForKey("numberThemeChanged") as Int32`.
2. `'Int32' is not identical to 'AnyObject'` in this line of code: `theme.setValue(newValueThemeChanges, forKey: "numberThemeChanged")`

Do you know how I can do it/what's wrong with my code?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: After setting the value. Save the NSManagedObjectContext object.

Comment: I saved the NSMangedObjectContext object.

Comment: You can check the object by fetching it from Core Data whether the value is updated or not.

Comment: How can I do this in Swift? Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not much familiar with swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Key-Value Coding methods

```
func valueForKey(key: String) -> AnyObject?
func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)
```

work with values of the type `AnyObject`, for an integer attribute these
are instances of `NSNumber`.

There is an automatic bridging between `Int` and `NSNumber`, but not
between `Int32` and `NSNumber` (and this has nothing to do with the
fact that you define the property as "Integer 32" in the Core Data
model inspector).

You have several options:

- Simply use a variable of type `Int`:

  ```
  var numChanges = theme.valueForKey("numberThemeChanged") as Int
  numChanges++
  theme.setValue(numChanges, forKey: "numberThemeChanged")
  ```
- Use `Int32` and convert from and to `NSNumber` explicitly:

  ```
  var numberOfChanges = (theme.valueForKey("numberThemeChanged") as NSNumber).intValue // Int32
  numberOfChanges++
  theme.setValue(NSNumber(int: numberOfChanges), forKey: "numberThemeChanged")
  ```
- Use Xcode -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclass ... and check the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" options. 
  This will give you a managed object subclass with the property

  ```
  @NSManaged var numberThemeChanged: Int32
  ```

  and you can access the property without Key-Value Coding:

  ```
  var numberOfChanges = theme.numberThemeChanged
  numberOfChanges++
  theme.numberThemeChanged = numberOfChanges
  ```

Here is a complete "create-or-update" example:

```
var theme : Entity!

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
var error : NSError?
if let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as [Entity]? {
    if result.count > 0 {
        // (At least) one object found, set `theme` to the first one:
        theme = result.first!
    } else {
        // No object found, create a new one:
        theme = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Entity
        // Set an initial value:
        theme.setValue(0, forKey: "numberThemeChanged")
    }
} else {
    println("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}

// Get value and update value:
var numChanges = theme.valueForKey("numberThemeChanged") as Int
numChanges++
theme.setValue(numChanges, forKey: "numberThemeChanged")

// Save context:
if !context.save(&error) {
    println("Save failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}

println(numChanges)
```

Comment: I don't know why but if I launch the my app the first time all works perfect. If I launch the app a 2nd time the number which I get back is 0 (has to be 1 because the code runs already 1 time). So it seems that the number wasn't stored the last time.

Comment: @horst: There are 2 possible reasons: 1) You did not save the context (but you claimed in a comment that you did). – 2) You create a *new* object each time, instead of fetching and updating an existing one.

Comment: @horst: I have added more sample code, that should help to get you started :)

Comment: @horst: I did already add sample code to my answer that shows how to fetch an existing object, or create a new one ...

Comment: Ok. I didn't saw it. Thank you for helping me!