# cant get the integer from core data atribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a core data model, where I added entity named CurrentLevel and an attribute called currentLevel and of int16 type. I am trying to save a simple integer into it like this:

```
    func saveCurrentLevel(cLevel: Int16){

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CurrentLevel",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)

    let curLevel = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    curLevel.setValue(NSNumber(short: cLevel), forKey: "currentLevel")

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

and this is my method for fetching

```
func fetchTheStuff() {

    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"CurrentLevel")

    //3
    var error: NSError?

    var fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]



    if let results = fetchedResults {
        println(results)
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I need that the fetched result would be just a simple integer and I cant find a way with core data to do so. Anyone know how ad/or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeFetchRequest()` returns an array of managed objects.
You have to get a single element (e.g. the first), then retrieve the
value of the "currentLevel" attribute (which is a `NSNumber`)
and finally extract the `Int16`:

```
if let results = fetchedResults {
    if count(results) > 0 {
        let curLevel = results[0] // NSManagedObject
        if let num = curLevel.valueForKey("currentLevel") as? NSNumber {
            let cLevel = num.shortValue // Int16
            println(cLevel)
        } else {
            println("level not set")
        }
    } else {
        println("no objects found")
    }
} else {
    println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
}
```

Instead of Key-Value coding with `setValue/valueForKey()` you can also
let Xcode create `NSManagedObject` subclasses. If you activate
the "use scalar properties for primitive data types" option then
you can access its

```
@NSManaged var currentValue: Int16
```

property directly.

Comment: Hm, now the program crashes : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ,,, at the line let num = currentLevel.valueForKey("currentLevel") as! NSNumber

Comment: @LukasPaskauskas: That would happen if the currentLevel attribute is not set for an object. I have changed the code so that this situation is detected.

Comment: yeah but thats the thing, I did set it. In my init method (its a sprite kit game) I first save some number ant then try to fetch it ( I know it doesnt make sense, i do it for testing purposes). By the way, I created the NSManagedObject subclass

Comment: @LukasPaskauskas: Could there be additional objects from previous runs of your app which don't have the value set? My sample code uses only the first found object. Of course you could iterate over the array of *all* found objects.

Comment: You are right; I tried on my real device now and it does work. You did answer my initial question, thanks a lot, but how do I fix this? I guess something is wrong with my save method?

Comment: @LukasPaskauskas: Your save method creates a *new* object on each call. If you want to store only a *single* object then you have to perform a fetch request first. If an object is found, *update* the attribute and save it. Otherwise create a new object and save. – Here is a similar example that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29447590/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

With Objective-C you need to store the int as a NSNumber when using Core Data. So if I was using an int, I would do it like this:

```
coreDataClass.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
```

I'm not sure if it's the same with Swift though.

Comment: neither am I, I am trying to learn the core data but so far have a hard time doing so. Not even sure what you mean here

Comment: Does Swift have NSNumbers? The main idea is that with Core Data you would have to store any int, float, double, etc, as a NSNumber. When you want to pull the data, you pull it as a NSNumber and then turn it into an int.